# How do you properly export SVG from node package?

Tags: node.js, npm, nodes

I'm having a very hard time determining how I can package assets to be used via a UI kit I've developed. I'd like these assets available within my package directly for portability.

My UI package has the following structure:

```
- src
  - index.ts
  - static
    - svg
      - icons
  - css
```

Within my package.json I have the following:

```json
{
  "exports": {
    ".": "./src",
    "./static/*": "./src/static/*"
  }
}
```

I've learned that this should work in theory however when I attempt to import the assets like so from another package:

```
import test from "ui/static/svg/icon/test.svg";
```

I receive the error:

```
Cannot find module 'ui/static/bottle/white_wine.svg' imported from ...
```

I'm wondering if perhaps the export path needs to be ./static/**/* or something similar? I've tried a silly amount of variations and I can't find descriptive documentation to understand how exports actually works.

Comment: It looks like the issue you're facing is related to how you're exporting and importing assets in your UI kit. The package.json exports field is used to define the entry points for the package, but it seems like you're using it to export static assets, which might not work as expected.

One way to solve this issue is to use a bundler like Webpack or Rollup to bundle your assets along with your source code. This allows you to import your assets in your code and make them available for consumption.